# How to sort rows based on a column added dynamically in jtable?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tablesorter

There already exist a jtable, and I need to add a column dynamically, then set table cell renderer for that column, the cell renderer is jlabel with icon. I already finished that.

My question is : Right now I need to sort that column based on different icons used in table cell renderer, so how to do that? Thank you.

There are the related code:

```
    JTable table；// the table is already existed, I cannot change it

    TableColumn column = new TableColumn();

    column.setHeaderValue("Icon");
    column.setCellRenderer(new IconCellRenderer());

    table.addColumn(column);


public class IconCellRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer
{
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  public IconCellRenderer()
  {
    super();
  }

  @Override
  public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable pTable, Object pValue,
      boolean pIsSelected, boolean pHasFocus, int pRow, int pColumn)
  {
    JLabel label = new JLabel();


    if (checkCondition(..))
    {
      label.setIcon(iconOne);
    } 
    else
    {
      label.setIcon(iconTwo));
    }

    label.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);

    return label;
  }

}
```

Comment: Posting some code or describing what you already attempted would help you to get an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For that purposes you can use `TableRowSorter`, and set `Comparator` to needed column. In that comparator you can compare values of cells and sorting them:

```
TableRowSorter<TableModel> sorter = new TableRowSorter<TableModel>(model);
sorter.setComparator(0, new Comparator<Object>() {

    @Override
    public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {
        return 0;
    }
});
table.setRowSorter(sorter);
```

`table` is your `JTable` , `model`  is model of your table.

read more about [sorting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#sorting) in `JTable`.

Comment: Thank you, and I'm still confused, in the table model, there is no value returned for the Icon cells, I used table cell renderer to set the icon, so in the compare method, will o1 and o2 have value? if they does, will they be instances of JLabel or Icon? will it still work? Anyway, I will give it a try.

Comment: o1 and o2 will be values from TableModel because of that they will not be `JLabel` or `Image`, they will be values from your cells, you can use your `checkCondition(..)` method from Renderer for determine conditions for comparrator.

Comment: Hi Alex, I tried to do it in the way you suggested, but there is a problem, I got exception: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: column beyond range of TableModel.
I think the reasion is that the column is added dynamically, the table model didn't change.

Comment: the code:    table.getColumnModel().addColumn(column);    
    TableRowSorter<MyTableModel> sorter = new TableRowSorter<MyTableModel>(tablemodel);
    
    sorter.setComparator(table.getColumnCount() -1, new Comparator<Object>()
    {

      @Override
      public int compare(Object pO1, Object pO2)
      {
        System.out.println("po1:" + pO1);
        System.out.println("po2" + pO2);
        return pO1.toString().compareTo(pO2.toString());
      }
    });
    
    table.setRowSorter(sorter);

Comment: and I tried to fireTableStructureChanged() just after the column is added, then the column is missed. I searched and found table.getColumnModel().addColumn() will fireTableStructureChanged() itself, but right now it didn't work, I don't know what to do, do you have some suggestions for me? Thank you.

Comment: @Jason for adding column use next code : `model.addColumn("NAME");` where model is your `TableModel`, instead of  ` table.getColumnModel().addColumn(column);`

Comment: I think it only work on DefaultTableModel, and I didn't use it and couldn't change that.

Comment: Show your model class, I'll try to change that.

Comment: en...I'm afraid of that I need to change the table model, I know how to change it, it's just very troublesome, that will be my last choice, I decide to do that now, thank you very much, Alex.